# Visual Studio Android Emulator - Video recording

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, emulation

I have a simple project up and running on VS for an android app which is just research at the moment. I want to record short (boring) videos to document people performing tasks. I have everything working fine. I have the android SDK, I have the emulator and I have the stock code which is everywhere on the internet. I have downloaded profiles for loads of android machines. APIs 15,19,23 on kitkat, marshmellow etc.

I have the permissions for video, audio, external storage etc in the manifest.

I think I am all goo other than I do not have a "stop" button for the video.

I have the corresponding camera operation working like a treat.

```
private void TakeAPicture(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
    App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format("myPhoto_{0}.jpg", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(App._file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

Then when the camera button is clicked, all is well picking up the content and storing it.

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode != Result.Ok)
    {
        // did not do what we wanted
        return;
    }

    // blah, blah, blah
}
```

My problem though is that when I use any emulator and click the video version, the video starts but never stops. Eventually it times out and I get the android "wait or kill" message and when I kill, it land in the OnActivityResult with a cancel resultCode (which is goodish)

Should I expect that the video in the emulator works. I am using the mocked video of the red / green box bouncing around.

here is my code which is triggered by a standard button click

```
private void TakeAVideo(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionVideoCapture);
    App._file = new File(App._dir, String.Format("myVideo_{0}.mp4", Guid.NewGuid()));
    intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(App._file));
    StartActivityForResult(intent, 200);
}
```

Thanks

[image: The emulator with an inactive record button]

Comment: I have in a way resolved this as a blocker but connecting to a real device but I would love to know why the emulators do not work. Do they simply not support video capture?

Comment: I've only recently started using the Visual Studio emulator for Android and I'm not able to get around this issue. I know I can use a real device, but this has been open for a couple of years now, is there any known resolution?